# How many $5$ digit natural numbers have at least one $5$ or one $7$?

Tags: combinations

There are $9 \cdot 10^4=90,000$ possible $5$ digit numbers.

Numbers with no $5$ is $8\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9 = 52,488$.

Numbers with no $7$ is $52,488$.

Numbers with at least one $5$ is $90,000 - 52,488$

Similarly numbers with at least one $7$ is $90,000-52,488$

So answer is $2(37,512)=75,024$

But this answer is wrong. Please provide correct solution..

Comment: You've double-counted those numbers which have both a 7 and a 9.

Comment: Count the "bad" numbers, neither $5$ nor $7$. Subtract from $9\times 10^4$.

Comment: You counted numbers that have both a $5$ and a $7$ twice. (For example, the number $10057$ is counted twice.)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Count the number of five digit-numbers that contain **NO** $5$'s **and  no** $7$'s; that gives us  $7\cdot 8^4$ such five-digit numbers.

The remainder ($90000 - 7\cdot 8^4$) will be the number of five digit numbers with *at least one* $5$ OR one $7$.